# Stopping "Back to Top Button" before footer

Tags: jquery, button, scroll, autoscroll

I have this code:

```
        $(function() {
// cache scroll to top button
var b = $('#back-top');
// Hide scroll top button
b.hide();
// FadeIn or FadeOut scroll to top button on scroll
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    // if you scroll more then 400px then fadein goto top button
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 500) {
        b.fadeIn();
    // otherwise fadeout button
    } else {
        b.fadeOut();
    }

});
// Animated smooth go to top
b.on('click', function(){
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 2000 );
    return false;
});
$('#back-top').)
});
```

Everything works really well, BUT I can't find a solution to stop the button scrolling before it hits the footer.:(
I hope someone here has a solution for my problem!?
Any help or advice would be very helpful! 
Thanks!

Update:

well I'm getting there!! 
I updated the fiddle with the new code: http://jsfiddle.net/q8DUC/6/ 
I implemented a line that enables the smooth scrolling to every href="#" and its working! 
 **BUT** I still have the old problem that the back-top element scrolls into the footer! I would apreaciate any ideas or help to make the backtop to stop before the footer! THX!!

**UPDATE 26/10/14:**

Got a bit further: http://jsfiddle.net/q8DUC/20/ 
Just don't know how I can avoid the jumping of the button!
Is there a way to stick the button to the bottom instead the top:0???

As always THANKS for every suggestion or help!

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle ?

Comment: yes. http://jsfiddle.net/q8DUC/
somehow the animation is not working but you can see the button is scrolling into the footer...

Comment: well I'm getting there!! 
I updated the fiddle with the new code: http://jsfiddle.net/q8DUC/6/
I implemented a line that enables the smooth scrolling to every href="#" and its working! BUT I still have the old problem that the back-top element scrolls into the footer! I would apreaciate any ideas or help to make the backtop to stop before the footer! THX!!

Answer (score 1):

In your fiddle you are using `$(window).load(function ()` and here you are using `$(function()`. It's not going to work with the former.

Also theres this line `$('#back-top').)` at the bottom of your code doing nothing. Delete that and everything should work fine.

Updated fiddle with http://jsfiddle.net/dJfpC/

(I also hid the scroll button, so it doesn't fade out when the page first loads).

Comment: Thanks Chris!
Its working. Still I do have the problem that the button scrolls into the footer! In the fiddle "Shamelessly stolen from Stack Overflow." is  supposed to be the footer...and the button runs into it! 
Any suggestion for this procblem?

Comment: yeap, check the first answer. :)

Comment: @user2899161 Sorry mate - i didn't read your question properly. Looks like you've solved your problem already. If not, heres an updated solution you can try: http://jsfiddle.net/djGrZ/ (won't work in jsfiddle but should work fine locally).

Comment: @Chris Thank you! I just tried it the fading and transition is working. But the button is still scrolling all the way down into the footer..despite the value I give the hight of the footer :( Any ideas what I might doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the rough solution for what you are trying to achieve.

Animation is not perfect here, but these is your working jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/q8DUC/5/

You should modify your function in the following way:

```
$('#backTop').hide();
$(window).scroll(function(){

 var stop = $('#footer').position().top - $(window).scrollTop();

 var bottomofbutton = $('#backTop').position().top + 100;

var bottom = stop - $('#backTop').height() + 'px';
console.log(bottom);
if ($(window).scrollTop() >100 ){
    $('#backTop').fadeIn();
} else {
$('#backTop').fadeOut();
};

if (stop <= bottomofbutton){
    $('#backTop').css('top',bottom);
} else if (stop >= bottomofbutton){

    $('#backTop').css({'bottom': '100px',
                       'top': ''});
}
});
```

I also renamed your #back-top id, because jQuery doesn't seem to work with it this way. I put #backTop instead.

Comment: Thanks Maxim! To be perfectly honest, this is the very first time that I have a hands on with javascript! I can see that your solution is working, but now the fade in/ out effect ist gone. :( 
I have no clue how to get your solution into my script!! Its too much for me to get the two scripts together...sorry!
Is there a chance that you could add your script to my script, please?

Comment: No problem, I updated jsfiddle, so it works just the way you want. Hope it helps this time.

Comment: I tried your solution, but also here the button is running into the footer of the page. :( But thanks anyway for the effort!

Comment: Ok try it now, I updated it again, this time I am pretty sure it works the way you want

Comment: I just tried it...
The fade out is not working..neither is the "stop before footer". I don't know what I'm doing wrong. With the script of Chris everything works except the footer issue! 
I'm probably too much of an amateur to get this working... 
Thanks A LOT anyway!